# Upload files and show them in web page using React

Tags: reactjs, file, web, show, uploading

I am trying **upload txt files using React**, and show these files or the names of the files front of the user,
to give him permission to change the file or to delete it.
This is my :

```
 import React from "react";

class Browse extends React.Component
{

state =  {selectedFile:[] , textFile: []};

//fileChangedHandler  Method
fileChangedHandler =event => {        
 for(var i=0;i<event.target.files.length;i++){         
       this.state.fileees =event.target.files;
       this.setState({selectedFile: event.target.files[i]})

    this.setState((state) => {
        const textFile=[...state.textFile,state.selectedFile.name];
        return {
          textFile,
        };
    });

  }  //for
  } //fileChangedHandler

 render(){
    return(
        <div className="Browse">
                <label for="myfile">Insert DNA Files:</label>
                <input type="file" onChange={this.fileChangedHandler} id="myfile" name="myfile" multiple/>                  
                <div>
                  {this.state.selectedFile.name}
                </div>
        </div>
    );
}

} //class


export default Browse;
```

Its works very good if I upload one file, I can see the file name, but Its not work if I upload multiple files.
I need the help for the problem,
**why if I upload more than one file, I can't show them in the web front of the user**

Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi Please check this example. Here I uploaded multiple files and shown file names in the page.**

```
import React from "react";

export default class FIleUploadExample extends React.Component {

    state = {
        files: []
    };

    fileUpload = (e) => {
        this.setState({files: [...e.target.files]});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <span>File Upload</span>
                <input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="file" onChange={this.fileUpload}/>
                <ul>
                    {
                        this.state.files.map((file, i) => <li key={i}>{file.name}</li>)
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Its work very well
Thank you !
-------------
But when I click Inspect and go to Component  to see the status of the
state, file seen empty .
Is that usual ?

Comment: @BhaaRizik, You are welcome bro. Components tab is React debugging tools. I dont have detail knowledge about it. may be its a bug for that tool but files objects are available in your code. you can do your further action with that files.

Comment: OK Thank you. My purpose is to send these files to the server that is written in c++ and to wok with them there.

Comment: Can you see the comment that I put, about the two other buttons ?  . Thanks

Comment: @BhaaRizik, I can see your comment but you should create new question for it. You are writing question on the place of answer. Can you please ask separate question and give me that link so that I can prepare example for you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61833074/change-the-file-after-uploading-in-react-js-reupload-files

Comment: @BhaaRizik, Please check my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61833074/change-the-file-after-uploading-in-react-js-reupload-files/61836211#61836211

Answer (score 0):

I need to add two buttons near of the name of the files :
first button name:"Delete" when the user  click it all the row disappear.
second button name: "Change" when the user click it he can upload another file, and the new file name must replace the old .
How can I do that ?

```
import React from "react";
import '../index.css';
import './dna.css';



export default class Browse extends React.Component {

    state = {
        files: [],
       // changeButtons:[],
    //    deleteButtons:[]
    };

    fileUpload = (e) => {
        this.setState({files: [...e.target.files]});
       // this.setState({changeButtons:[<button>Change</button>]});
       // this.setState({deleteButtons:[<button onClick={(e)=>this.onDelete(id)}>Delete</button>]});
    };

        Change(id){
            console.log("Change Function");
        }

    Delete(id) {
        console.log("ssss")
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          files: prevState.files.filter(files => files.id !== id),
        }))
        console.log(this.state.files.name);
      }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Browse">
               <label>Insert DNA Files:</label>
                <input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="file" onChange={this.fileUpload}/>
                <table className="filesName">

                    {

                        this.state.files.map((file, i) => <tr key={i}>
                                                            <td style={{textAlign:"left"}}>{file.name} : </td>
                                                            <td><button onClick={() => this.Change(i)}>Change</button></td>
                                                            <td><button onClick={() => this.Delete(i)}>Delete</button></td>
                                                          </tr>)
                    }

                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```