# Forget password in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my **log in** page I have a button "Forget my password",
I need, when I click in this button to go to the correct page.

In my current code, when I click "forget my password", it shows under the login, which mean at the same page I see the "login" and the "forget password".

What I need is to see just the  "forget my password" page.

Here is my code :

```
import React from "react";
import ForgetPage from "../ForgetPasswrod/Forgotpass"
import {Link,useParams,  useRouteMatch,Route, Switch, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

class Forget extends React.Component{

   Forget password -

render(){
  //  let  match = useRouteMatch();
    return(
        <div>

        <BrowserRouter>
        {" "} <Link to="/forgetPassword"  className="forget">Forgot password?</Link>
        <Switch>
          <Route  path="/forgetPassword" exact strict component={(ForgetPage)} />
        </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>


        </div>);

}

}

export default Forget;
```

The page of log in

```
import React from "react";
import Username from "./UserName";
import Password from "./Password";
import Submit from "./Submit";
import Rememberme from "./RememberMe";
import Cancel from "./Cancel";
import ForgetPass from "./Forget"

class Hub extends React.Component {


state={userName:"Log", password : "In"}

callbackUsername=(user)=>{
    this.setState({userName: user});
    console.log("---"+user)
}


callbackPassword = (pass) => {
     this.setState({ password: pass});
  }


render(){
return(
<div>
<h1> {this.state.userName} {this.state.password}</h1>
    <form className="modal-content animate">

        <Username userHub={this.callbackUsername}/>
        <Password passHub={this.callbackPassword}/>

        <Submit/>
        <Rememberme/>

        <div className="container">
            <Cancel/>     
        <ForgetPass/>


        </div>
    </form> 
</div>

);
}
}

export default Hub;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this example:

```
import React from "react";

export default class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {forgot: false};
    }

    login() {
        alert('Login will work here');
    }
    forgot() {
        this.setState({forgot: true})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.forgot === false && <div>
                    Username: <input/> <br/>
                    Password: <input/><br/>
                    <button onClick={this.forgot.bind(this)}>Forgot</button>
                    <button onClick={this.login.bind(this)}>Login</button>
                </div>}
                {this.state.forgot === true && <ForgotPassword/>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class ForgotPassword extends React.Component {

    reset() {
        alert('Password is sent to your email');
    }

    render() {
        return (<div><h1>Write your email</h1>
            <input/>
            <button onClick={this.reset.bind(this)}>Reset Password</button>

        </div>)
    }
}
```