# Reading multiple files cotent's React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file

I'm trying to read multiple files with React.js, but my code reads only one file and doesn't read the rest. Any suggestion?

Thanks

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        files: [],
        changedFileIndex: -1,
        fileReader : null
    };
    this.fileUploaderRef = React.createRef();
}

 handleFileReader = (e)=>{
    console.log("handleFileReader")
     var content =this.state.fileReader.result;
     console.log(content);
 }

  handleFileChosen(file){
    console.log("handleFileChosen")
    console.log(file.result)
     this.state.fileReader=new FileReader();
     this.state.fileReader.onloadend = this.handleFileReader;
     this.state.fileReader.readAsText(file);   

 }


async readAllFiles (AllFiles) {
    console.log("readAllFiles")
    //console.log(AllFiles[0].name)
   AllFiles.map((file)=>
       {  
               this.handleFileChosen(file)
        }
    );

 }
```

In the array of files, we need to loop over the files and send to the other functions in order to write content of each file in the array.
After some debugging, for example for 2 files, it looks like the code executes 'handleFileChosen' 2 times, and then goes to handleFileReader 2 times which is probably what's wrong but I'm not sure how to fix this. Instead, it should be like this: execute 'HandleFileReader', then execute 'handleFileChosen', then again 'HandleFileReader', then execute 'handleFileChosen'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arr.map()` is `synchronous` and FileReader works `asynchronously`, use `Promise.all` on the array returned by map

Ref:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

I have modified your functions to read all files

```
handleFileChosen = async (file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = () => {
      resolve(fileReader.result);
    };
    fileReader.onerror = reject;
    fileReader.readAsText(file);
  });
}


readAllFiles = async (AllFiles) => {
  const results = await Promise.all(AllFiles.map(async (file) => {
    const fileContents = await handleFileChosen(file);
    return fileContents;
  }));
  console.log(results);
  return results;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62601703/axios-request-error-ssl-connection-error-react-js

Answer (score 0):

Please find the complete code to show how to read multiple file contents. In `handleUpload` event I prepared `AllFiles` and call the function `readAllFiles` by passing `AllFiles`. Then I called `readFileContents` under `readAllFiles` that actually is reading file contents. As FileReader works `asynchronously` so need to use `Promise` here.

**[Here is Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/read-multiple-file-contents-ubvs6)**

**Here is the Code:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class FileReaderExample extends Component {

    readFileContents = async (file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = () => {
                resolve(fileReader.result);
            };
            fileReader.onerror = reject;
            fileReader.readAsText(file);
        });
    }
    readAllFiles = async (AllFiles) => {
        const results = await Promise.all(AllFiles.map(async (file) => {
            const fileContents = await this.readFileContents(file);
            return fileContents;
        }));
        console.log(results, 'resutls');
        return results;
    }

    handleUpload = (e) => {
        let AllFiles = [];
        [...e.target.files].map(file => AllFiles.push(file));

        this.readAllFiles(AllFiles).then(result => {
            let preview = document.getElementById('showText');
            let allFileContents = "";
            result.map(res =>{
                allFileContents += res + '<br/>'
            })
            preview.innerHTML = allFileContents;
        })
            .catch(err => {
                alert(err);
            });
    }

    render = () => {

        return (<div>
                <input type="file" multiple onChange={(e) => this.handleUpload(e)}/>
                <div id="showText">Choose text File</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```