# Axios request error SSL connection error React JS

Tags: reactjs, ssl, post, get, xmlhttprequest

I have this post request in React JS :
I need to pass files using Rest API and receive a response to the react
but when I do that I get error .
Rest Api written in python and there I do some process on the files

```
 let postR = []

    results.map(async result => {
      // const response = await Promise.axios.post(
      postR.push(
        axios.post(
          'https://52.14.247.16:5000/process',
          { result },
          { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
        )
      )
    })
    Promise.all(postR).then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.getRequest()
    })
```

and here the get request that I sent from the react to do something there:

```
  getRequest = async () => {
    axios
      .get(
        'https://52.14.247.16:5000/start/' +
          this.props.maxLen +
          '+' +
          this.props.minLen +
          '+' +
          this.props.maxDistance +
          '+' +
          this.props.minDistance +
          '+' +
          this.props.MicrobeType +
          '+' +
          this.state.files.length
      )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        //alert(response.data.value);
        console.log(response.data.value)
        // document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =response.data.value;

        this.downloadTxtFile(response.data.value)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
        alert('Problem at the server\nTry later\n' + error)
      })
  }
```

so I receive errors like that :

```
xhr.js:178 POST https://52.14.247.16:5000/process net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR


createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)


POST https://52.14.247.16:5000/process net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I need a help !

Comment: Hard to investigate here. Is any self signed certificate involved? Does the get request work when you enter the URL in the browser? Do you have any other working client for this server?

Comment: yes , everything works well, I tried to use http and process worked well, but when I deployed to AWS, they request to use https request. so I changed http to https and received this error.

Comment: @BhaaRizik looks like `ssl` not set properly, simple get request without https is working, http://52.14.247.16:5000/start/12+12+12+12+1+12 giving `{"value":""}`